# How to to forbid access my site from ip address+port using nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a django app with gunicorn running on port 2333.In nginx.conf I set

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        location / {
        proxy_cache my_cache;

        proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2333;
        expires 30d;
                }
```

now I can view my django app on address http://ipaddress:2333 and mydomain.com
but I don't want users to view my site by http://ipaddress:2333 .How to allow nginx only use mydomain.com to access my site.

I have tried to use "server default".It not worked.

```
server {
        listen 2333 default;
        server_name _;
        return 500;
}
```

Comment: How are you running gunicorn?

Answer (score 2):

Nginx has nothing to do with that. Your Gunicorn (Django) app is listening on port 2333. Therefore, you can bypass nginx by connecting to http://$SERVER:2333. It will work even if you stop nginx.

What you need to do is tell gunicorn to listen only on the localhost, e.g. with `--bind=127.0.0.1:2333`. Then port 2333 will be accepting connections only from the local network interface.

Comment: Thanks,I set gunicorn to run on bind 127.0.0.1:2333 and it worked.